# IOS6 interface builder auto layout :CRASH Unable to install constraint on view

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios6

When I was trying to add all view by auto layout, it comes out with the following message:

```
CRASH Unable to install constraint on view. 
Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  
That's illegal. 
constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x756b510 UIPickerView:0x756f220.top == 
LoginView:0x75e9d30.top + 106> view:<LoginView: 0x75e9d30; 
frame = (0 15; 320 430); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x75e9dc0>>
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Finally, i used another xib to handle IPHONE5 long screen problem.
Since i don't have enough time to understanding...

Comment: Same here, is not happening on my iPhone but in iPad and iPod.

Comment: just posted my solution in below, you can have a look.But sure....it is not a good solution for using auto layout, because i do it in another way..

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833070/nsgenericexception-reason-unable-to-install-constraint-on-view)

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same exact issue on a picker view. Tapping a input field opened the picker view, I then chose something on picker view and closed it. When going to another view and then back again to pickerview I got the error mentioned. I solved it by turning off autolayout. This can be done on the file inspector, just untick the autolayout.

Answer (score -1):

QUick tips:
you have to create 3 XIB for one View Controller

1. YourViewController.xib,
2. YourViewController-568.xib,
3. YourViewController~ipad.xib

and add the following code in every YourViewController.m 
then it will load different view for different user Device

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   // if(nibNameOrNil == nil){
        nibNameOrNil = @"YourViewController";

        if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 480){

                nibNameOrNil = @"YourViewController-568";
                // iphone5+
            }else{
                // older than iphone5
            }
        }
   // }

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self){

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: ctrl-K is your friend for indentation :-) Also note, that numbered list items require "1. "(note the space after the period) instead of "1)"