# Using custom View with Storyboard without adding it twice

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm using Storyboard and trying to reuse a View for different ViewControllers.

For that, I created a custom .xib (`MyCustomView.xib`) and class (`MyCustomView`) as suggested pretty much everywhere.

In my Storyboard I set the custom view to be of type `MyCustomView`.

In `MyCustomView.xib`, set First Responder to `MyCustomView`.

In `MyCustomView.m`, I added the following method:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){
        UIView *myCustomView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview: myCustomView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Problem is, `[self addSubview: myCustomView]` adds a new `MyCustomView` to existing `MyCustomView`, so the view is added twice.

How can I get rid of one of the two?

**EDIT**

My question is not really clear, so I thought some screen caps would help.

Here is my Storyboard with a custom view. Custom class is set to `MyCustomView`.
[image: Storyboard with MyCustomView]

(I also added a grey background and a label for testing purpose only)

Now, in `MyCustomView.xib`, I set File's owner to be of Class `MyCustomView`:
[image: MyCustomView.xib]

And add outlets for title Label and imageView:
[image: MyCustomView.xib]

With the initWithCoder method as written above, this works fine, except when I debug I can see this:
[image: MyCustomView.m]
So `self` is of course of type `MyCustomView`, as chosen in the Storyboard, but it contains 2 subviews :

- First is the test label from my storyboard
- Second is the view from `MyCustomView.xib`, itself containing a Label and image view. **That's this view I want to get rid of**.

Comment: The other way to do this, is to do it all in the storyboard -- make your custom view in one controller, and you can copy and paste it into other controllers (delete their default views first, before you paste).

Comment: That may be easier, but each time I modify the view in a controller, have to modify it in each other, that's why I want it in a .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

What is *self* ?

Here, it is the MyCustomView you just instantiated. So, you're adding a new UIView (not MyCustomView) to your new MyCustomView instance created by the *initWithCoder* method.

*initWithCoder* is the method called when loading your storyboard view.

If you want to instantiate a new MyCustomView **in your MyCustomViewController** you have to call

```
MyCustomView *newInstance = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
[self addSubview:newInstance];
```

Where *self* is the instance of MyCustomViewController in your storyboard.

---

**EDIT**

OK, I understand better your question. 
If you want to load the MyCustomView nib file, you don't need to create a class for it (except if you have specific variables you want to access in it. 
Just do what you're doing here, but in the view controller, which will be the *self*. :)

You might want to have a look at : [How to load a UIView using a nib file created with Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder)

---

**EDIT 2**

Ok, I think I get it :

- delete the MyCustomView in your Storyboard.
- create a class MyView or whatever which you attach to the view named "View" in your Storyboard.
- in the init method of your class you instantiate your MyCustomView nib
- add the resulting UIView to the views stack like you did it.

*self* will be MyView (present in the Storyboard), MyCustomView won't appear in the storyboard but created programmatically in the init method of MyView.h

You will have to add constraints programmatically. Here is a post that can be helpful: [Adding View Programatically With Auto Layout Gives 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060704/adding-view-programatically-with-auto-layout-gives-nsgenericexception-reason)

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I'm adding a new UIView to MyCustomView. But how to get rid of this particular UIView? Cause in my .xib file, it represents MyCustomView...
Thank you

Comment: Make it simple :-) If you begin a new project in XCode, the default view will be of type UIView in Storyboard. If you want it to be of type MyCustomView, you have only to type it in the right panel (third tab -> custom class). **Don't instantiate a new view in the init of your custom view class**. If you want to instantiate a new view elsewhere, just do like I wrote in this answer.

Comment: I edited my question with screen caps as I'm afraid it wasn't very clear. I do have specific variables so I need a class for it. Also, I like my approach since I don't have to add any code in my view controllers (it's only handled by the storyboard and my widget view).

Comment: What are you trying to make actually? Because this code: "UIView *myCustomView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview: myCustomView];" does pretty well you are asking him to do - adding new instance of MyCustomView to existing (self) instance of MyCustomView!

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm trying to add subviews and constraints of MyCustomView xib to existing (self) instance of MyCustomView, with no success.