# Getting NSGeneric Exception while updating constraints programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, exception, autolayout, constraints

Here is my code:

```
int x= 17;
int y = 27;
int width = 287;
int height = 181;
int mainview_height = 568;
int x_spacer = 0;
int y_spacer = 0;
int width_spacer = 320;
int height_spacer = 27;

    UIView *view_spacer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_spacer, y_spacer, width_spacer, height_spacer)];
    [view_spacer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [view_spacer setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.mainView addSubview:view_spacer];
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.mainView addSubview:view1];

    [view_spacer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width_spacer/height_spacer constant:0.0f]];
    [self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0.0f]];
    [self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:width_spacer/mainview_height constant:0.0f]];
    [self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [view_spacer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0.0f]];
    [view1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                         multiplier:width/height constant:0.0f]];
    [self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight                                                        multiplier:width/mainview_height constant:0.0f]];
    [self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

I got the following error while updating the auto layout constraints

> The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint:
>       When added to
>   a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or
>   the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be
>   resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView
>   _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug. 2015-07-18 12:54:02.469 LandCorp Cleaning App[2022:64687] View hierarchy
>   unprepared for constraint.    Constraint:
>       Container
>   hierarchy:  >    View not found in container hierarchy:
>   >  That view's superview: > 2015-07-18 12:54:02.472 LandCorp Cleaning
>   App[2022:64687] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view. 
>   Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of
>   the view?  That's illegal.
>   constraint: view:>'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010799dc65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000107636bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010799db9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205     3   Foundation 
>   0x00000001071c8479 -[NSLayoutConstraint
>   _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 187   4   UIKit                               0x0000000108406786 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
>   + 411     5   UIKit                               0x0000000108406a14 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
>   + 30  6   UIKit                               0x0000000108406b3c -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 243    7   LandCorp Cleaning App               0x00000001070e7e47 -[InspectionDetails populateDataViews] + 2007    8   LandCorp Cleaning App               0x00000001070e748c -[InspectionDetails
>   connection:didReceiveData:] + 1404    9   CFNetwork
>
>   0x00000001097dbd6c __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal
>   _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 69     10  CFNetwork                           0x00000001097dbd10
>   -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 199   11  CFNetwork                           0x00000001097dbe77
>   -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48     12  CFNetwork                           0x00000001097c6089
>   _ZL30_NSURLConnectionDidReceiveDataP16_CFURLConnectionPK8__CFDatalPKv + 79    13  CFNetwork                           0x00000001096a85e0 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic29_delegate_didReceiveDataArrayEv_block_invoke
>   + 302     14  CFNetwork                           0x0000000109778a71 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2
>   + 273     15  CFNetwork                           0x00000001096965d6 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 72   16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001078a4354 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68    17  CFNetwork
>
>   0x0000000109696497 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 133   18 
>   CFNetwork                           0x00000001096962d6
>   _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 256    19  CFNetwork                           0x00000001096960ec _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72  20 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001078d1431
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001078c72fd
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269   22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001078c6934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868     23  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001078c6366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     24  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010aec3a3e GSEventRunModal + 161  25  UIKit
>   0x0000000107d968c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282   26  LandCorp Cleaning App
>   0x00000001070e897f main + 111     27  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000109f41145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Please give me some suggestion how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833070/nsgenericexception-reason-unable-to-install-constraint-on-view)?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have also changed the [view_spacer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0.0f]]; to [self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0.0f]]; It removes the exception. But the views are not getting displayed.

Comment: please suggest why the views are not getting displayed